# What is the number of integer solutions of the following equation ? Find the solution without computing 9 combinations.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The equation is:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6<10$$
with $x_i\geq 0$ for $i=1,2,\dots,6$.

- What is the number of integer solutions of the following equation ?
- Find the solution without computing 9 combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is equivalent to 
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6+y=9$$
with $x_i\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$.
Then, by using [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), we get
$$\binom{9+6}{6}.$$

Comment: @Merve Gürsu Any further doubt?

Comment: I think the answer is 5005. Is that all?

Comment: Okay, sorry :)  Thank you for all your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Write

$$x_1+x_2+...+x_6=9-y$$

with $y \ge 0$ and solve

$$x_1+x_2+...+x_6+y=9$$

for integer solution.